# import multiple files R

Tags: r, csv, raster

I hope you can help me. I have been trying to import multiple raster datasets into R, recode missing values for each raster data imported, link them to zipcodes and then export each raster data as a csv file with different names.
I am trying to use a loop but so far I have only got errors. This is as far as I have gotten (dont laugh):

## import all 24 raster datasets

```
file_names=as.list(dir(pattern="home.*"))
listy<-lapply(file_names,raster, band=1)
names(listy) <- paste0("hour", seq_along(0:23))
```

so now I have all the raster datasets in a list (listy) and I just need to run the following commands on each one:

## example for element 1 of listy

```
listy$hour1_r<-listy$hour1
listy$hour1_r[listy$hour1_r==9999]<-NA
y <- extract(listy$hour1_r, zipcoords)
hour1_zipcode <- cbind(zipid,y)
write.table(hour1_zipcode,file="home\\hour1.csv",sep=",",row.names=F)
```

How can I do this with a loop?
I would very much appreciate any suggestions that you may have!

Thank you!!!
m

Answer (score 0):

Make a function out of your commands:

```
f <- function(listy,filename) {
  listy$hour1_r<-listy$hour1
  listy$hour1_r[listy$hour1_r==9999]<-NA
  y <- extract(listy$hour1_r, zipcoords)
  hour1_zipcode <- cbind(zipid,y)
  write.table(hour1_zipcode,file=filename,sep=",",row.names=F)
}
```

Run your command on all elements:

```
mapply(f, listy, filename= paste0("home\\hour",seq_along(listy),".csv"))
```

Note that you don't actually want `mapply` to return anything, so you could wrap it in invisible:

```
invisible(mapply(f, listy, filename= paste0("home\\hour",seq_along(listy),".csv")))
```

You could also do this in a for loop:

```
filenames = paste0("home\\hour",seq_along(list),".csv")
for (i in seq_along(listy)) f(listy[[i]],filenames[[i]])
```

Answer (score -1):

cant you just do it in a for loop?

```
for(i in 1:length(listy)) { 

listy[[i]] <- listy[[i]]
etc
}
```

or with lapply

```
lapply(listy, function(x) { 
  x[[i]] <- x[[i]]
  etc
  } 
)
```

Comment: Note that both the `for` loop is incorrect and the `lapply` are incorrect.