# Importing and merging .txt or .csv files in R

Tags: r, import, merge

I am a "close to zero knowledge" R user and need help.

I have 50 files in a folder, each file representing 50 walking repetitions. Each file is a 105 row X 9 column dataframe. I am preparing my dataframe for PCA and need some functionalities.

1) How can I import iteratively all 50 files in R?
2) How can I merge the first column, and only rows (5 to 105) of each file for all 50 files to create a 101 X 50 dataframe?
3) Do step 2) iteratively for the remaining 8 columns of each file?
4) Label the column of the merged dataframe with the initial file name.

I hope help can be rendered.

Kind regards,
Bernard

Comment: It's best to do one question at a time. Importing files `en batche` (sounds French, right?) is easy and has been covered here many a time (search " import multiple files [r]"). You will get questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575224/import-multiple-files-r) one. If you read in all the files into a list, you can do `do.call("cbind", your.list)`. I also suggest you read on [Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

To import files in R, you need to know the filename. You can get the filenames if you're in the directory, and you use list.files(). However, the best way to iteratively import files is to have the filenames be numbered such as data1.csv, data2.csv, etc. That way, you can use a simple loop to create the filenames and import one by one.

For part 2, just pull out a vector of what you need and then cbind them iteratively together. So something like

```
retData <- data.frame()

for(f in filenames){

    tempData <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE, sep=",")
    bindData <- tempData[5:105, 1]

    retData <- cbind(retData, bindData)

}
```

Then for part 3, just make a loop inside the outer loop that iterates through the columns.

Finally for part 4, once you have the filenames, you can easily set the column names by

```
colnames(retData) <- filenames
```